# SQL index_description. nonclustered located on INDEXES / PRIMARY

Tags: sql, database, t-sql, ssms

When I select a Table in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio and hit "Alt+F1".

I see in 2 different nonclusetered indexes with different descriptions:
nonclustered located on INDEXES
nonclustered located on PRIMARY.

I do not expect it to be any different, can anyone explain what is the difference between these?

Comment: [This is the name of the filegroup or partition scheme that the index is created on](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/45351/meaning-of-nonclustered-located-on-primary/45352#45352)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the name of the filegroup or partition scheme that the index is created on.

More information here:
[Meaning of “nonclustered located on primary”](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/45351/meaning-of-nonclustered-located-on-primary/45352#45352)

*Thanks to Martin Smith for the answer.*